# Prolog rule is returning an exception with semi-colon usage

Tags: prolog, logic, rules

So, whilst I cannot share the exact code, I have something like this:

```
belongsTo(A,B) :- bag(A,B); shoe(A,B); sunglasses(A,B).
```

If bag B belongs to person A, or shoe B belongs to person A, or sunglass B belongs to person A, then yes should be returned. When I type in a query to check if a bag belongs to a person, it works well. But when I type in a query to check if a bag belongs to a person (and it should return no), I get the following error:

uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,component/2),belongsTo/0)

For example:`belongsTo(bag, wrongPerson)` returns the error instead of No as it should.

Same thing happens if the query tests for a shoe or sunglasses instead of a bag.

Comment: You say your query is `belongsTo(bag, wrongPerson)` which is `belongsTo/2` with two arguments but the error says you are querying `belongsTo/0`  which is belongsTo with no arguments, which is a different predicate. Or, would be, if it existed.

Comment: Show your query. `belongsTo/0` is of arity 0 rather than 2. Which indicates that your query is bad. Also, why not use e.g. `person_object_belongs(Person, Object)...` - it's far clearer than names of "A" and "B", which convey no meaning.

Comment: You have to have a reproducible example even if you can't share your exact code.